# How to debug DataFlow exception

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am receiving the following error condition in an Azure Data Factory data flow that looks like the picture below.

[image]

```
{"message":"DSL stream  has parsing errors\nLine 11 Position 207: token recognition error at: '\\n'. Details:DSL stream  has parsing errors\nLine 11 Position 207: token recognition error at: '\\n'","failureType":"UserError","target":"df_ReplicaSync","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}
```

How does one debug this?  It has no reference to any activity, operation, or parameter?  I tried looking at the line in the JSON code for each activity in the data flow but no help.

UPDATE:

There was a line feed in the expression builder window where you build the T-SQL.  It will not complain about it but it will add a new line character that will cause this issue at runtime.

[image]

[image]

When viewing the script as Mark suggested

[image]

Comment: Debugging such error in DF is a real challenge. "target":"df_ReplicaSync" is in the message, which appears to reference your Target (did this change from Sink?) block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSL is referring to the data flow script (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script) that is behind the map. You can see it by clicking on the Script button on the top right. If you click on it for your data flow, you can find the location of the error via Line 11, Pos 207.

Comment: Good answer. You save my life!